# Meshes in Modelnstance

Tags: java, android, 3d, opengl-es, libgdx

is there a way to duplicate meshes from the Model? as far as I know, Multiple instances can be created from the same Model, you got copy of Material but all sharing the same meshes and textures of the Model.

as an example we make two softbodies and two instances:

```java
ModelBuilder builder = new ModelBuilder();
        builder.begin();  
        builder.part(
            meshPart, material);
model = builder.end();

instance = new ModelInstance(model);
instance2 = new ModelInstance(model);

render() {
softBody.getVertices(mesh.getVerticesBuffer(), softBody.getNodeCount(), mesh.getVertexSize(), 0);
softBody.getWorldTransform(instance.transform);

softBody2.getVertices(mesh.getVerticesBuffer(), softBody2.getNodeCount(), mesh.getVertexSize(), 0);
softBody2.getWorldTransform(instance2.transform);
}
```

when I apply force on one instance the other follows the same movements. how do you copy meshes without creating a new model? is that possible?

thank you